# Получение среднего значения

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как в Pandas можно получить (преобразовать) среднее значение каждой ячейки колонки, если в ячейках указан интервал? Например:

- '15,000-19,999' - 17500,
- '125,000-149,999' - 137500,
- '> $1,000,000' -
  оставляем 1000000

То есть в итоге, получить колонку со средними значениями в ячейках.
Исходная колонка:

```
    data['Q29']
    1                  NaN
    2                  NaN
    3                  NaN
    4        25,000-29,999
    5                  NaN
                 ...      
    23993              NaN
    23994              NaN
    23995    25,000-29,999
    23996    15,000-19,999
    23997              NaN
    Name: Q29, Length: 23997, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при исходном фрейме:

```
               1
0               
0  25,000-29,999
1  25,000-29,999
2  15,000-19,999
```

Можно, например, так:

```
df["mean"] = df[1].str.replace(",",".").str.split("-").apply(lambda x: sum(pd.to_numeric(x))/len(x))
```

получите

```
               1     mean
0                        
0  25,000-29,999  27.4995
1  25,000-29,999  27.4995
2  15,000-19,999  17.4995
```